# param un-optional semicolon on struct

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018, semicolon-inference

I am currently updating a lot CF 11 code to CF 2018. One of the things I like is that semicolons are options most of the time. Having said that, I am stuggling with the thinking behind this:

**Error**

```
<cfscript>
rc = {}

param rc.data2 = ""
</cfscript>
```

> You cannot use a variable reference with "." operators in this context
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> A script statement beginning with param on line 3, column 1. A
> cfscript tag beginning on line 1, column 2.

**Not an error**

```
<cfscript>
rc = {}

param rc.data2 = "";
</cfscript>
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a gripe, not a question.

Comment: Tons of this kind of stuff upgrading from ACF 8 to 9, 9 to 10, 9 to 11, 10 to 11, yadda, yadda, yadda. :)

Comment: Technically...there is no question...